# Ho can I get rid of *.exe.manifest files form the MSVC compiled exe files?

Tags: c++, c, manifest, exe

I beg my apologies beforehand before asking some silly questions,
but I searched the web at my capacity but not found any answer that works in my case.
My question is:
How can I get rid of the embarrassing ***.exe.manifest** associated with the  ***.exe**,
when codes compiled with MS Visual Studio 2008 from a **[bakefile](http://www.bakefile.org/index.html)** generated makefile?

First I created a bakefile as follows:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" ?>
> <!--
> ===========================================
> Plain EXE
> ===========================================
> -->
> <makefile>
>
>
> <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
>
> <!-- HERE OUR PROJECT GOES -->
> <exe id="MyApplication">
>   <app-type> console </app-type>
>   <!-- Compiler Specific -->
>   <cflags>/TC /W4 /Za </cflags> <!-- Compile code as C. /TP , as C++
>   /Tc <source file> means this file is C only, /Tp means this file is C++ only.
>   /O1 minimize space, /O2 maximize speed, /Os favor code space, /Ot favor code speed.
>   /Wall enable all warnings (gives warning on own headers like stdio.h).
>   /Wp64 enable 64 bit porting warnings (will be deprecated in future). 
>   /Za disable extensions, can be used with plain console apps but not with gui apps. -->
>
>     <!-- <define>SOMEMACRO</define> -->
>     <!-- <define>_OPENGLUT_STATIC</define> --> <!-- use underscore '_' before macro -->
>     <!-- <include>../include/foo</include> -->
>     <!-- <include>C:\xtralibs\appu</include> -->
>     <!-- <include>C:\xtralibs\OpenGLUT-0.6.3vc</include> -->
>     <!-- <headers>utils.h additionalheader.h</headers> -->
>
>        <sys-lib> user32.lib kernel32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib comctl32.lib ole32.lib
>          winmm </sys-lib> <!-- OpenGLUT_static.lib OpenGLUT.lib glu32.lib opengl32.lib -->
>     <!-- <sys-lib>png</sys-lib> -->
>     <!-- <sys-lib>OpenGLUT</sys-lib> -->
>     <!-- <sys-lib>z</sys-lib> -->
>     <!-- <lib-path>/usr/lib/mysql</lib-path> -->
>     <!-- <lib-path>C:\xtralibs\OpenGLUT-0.6.3vc</lib-path> -->
>                      <!-- note that hardcoding library paths like this is a bad
>        idea, it's done here only for the sake of simplicity;
>        in real bakefile, an <option> would be used -->
>        <!--<library>mylib</library> -->
>        <ldflags> /ENTRY:"mainCRTStartup"</ldflags> <!-- required for gui apps only,
>        >can be used with console apps also -->
>
>   <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
>
>   <!-- ~~~~~~~~ Compiler Specific definition Ends ~~~~~~~~~~ -->
>
>     <!-- COMMON -->
>     <!-- <win32-res> resource.rc </win32-res> -->
>     <sources> test.c </sources>
>
> </exe>
> <!-- HERE OUR PROJECT ENDS -->
>
> <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
> </makefile>
> ```

Then I created a batch file as:

> bakefile -f msvc -o Makefile.mak testing.bkl
>
> call "%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
> nmake -f Makefile.mak
> cmd

After that a Makefile was created as:

> ```
> # =========================================================================
> #     This makefile was generated by
> #     Bakefile 0.2.9 (http://www.bakefile.org)
> #     Do not modify, all changes will be overwritten!
> # =========================================================================
>
>
>
> # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
> # These are configurable options:
> # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> # C compiler 
> CC = cl
>
> # Standard flags for CC 
> CFLAGS = 
>
> # Standard preprocessor flags (common for CC and CXX) 
> CPPFLAGS = 
>
> # Standard linker flags 
> LDFLAGS = 
>
>
>
> # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
> # Do not modify the rest of this file!
> # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ### Variables: ###
>
> MYAPPLICATION_CFLAGS = /MD /DWIN32 /D_CONSOLE /TC /W4 /Za $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
> MYAPPLICATION_OBJECTS =  \
>   MyApplication_test.obj
>
> ### Conditionally set variables: ###
>
>
>
> ### Targets: ###
>
> all: MyApplication.exe
>
> clean: 
>   -if exist .\*.obj del .\*.obj
>     -if exist .\*.res del .\*.res
>   -if exist .\*.pch del .\*.pch
>   -if exist MyApplication.exe del MyApplication.exe
>   -if exist MyApplication.ilk del MyApplication.ilk
>   -if exist MyApplication.pdb del MyApplication.pdb
>
>   MyApplication.exe: $(MYAPPLICATION_OBJECTS)
>    link /NOLOGO /OUT:$@  /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /ENTRY:"mainCRTStartup" $(LDFLAGS) @<<
>   $(MYAPPLICATION_OBJECTS)   user32.lib kernel32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib comctl32.lib ole32.lib
>   winmm.lib
>  <<
>
>  MyApplication_test.obj: .\test.c
>   $(CC) /c /nologo /TC /Fo$@ $(MYAPPLICATION_CFLAGS) .\test.c
> ```

Finally my code compiled with Visual Studio 2008.
Up-to this everything was fine.
Now the main problem comes.
Visual Studio creates a manifest file which is actually a plain xml file.
When I delete the manifest, my exe does not run.

- Can I manage to create the bakefile in such a way so that the compiled exe would never require the manifest?
  I mean some compiler/linker flags I would like to add to solve this, but I don't know this flag.

I'm eagerly waiting for your help.

Comment: When a tool like this can't handle the common build scenario for a common compiler then they are pretty useless.  Mt.exe must be run to embed the manifest in the EXE.  Best to avoid wasting time on it, this project looks dead to me.

Comment: The manifest is stored in the resource section of a module. Edit the .rc file and remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to solve this. Bakefile already has a xml-tag called

```
<postlink-command></postlink-command>
```

where we can run mt.exe to embed the manifest and finally delete the manifest.

The C code is:

```
/* main.c */
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
 printf("Hello world!\n");
 system ("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}
```

The bakefile is (plain_exe.bkl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
===========================================
A SIMPLE EXE
===========================================
-->
<makefile>
   <exe id="hello">
       <sources> main.c </sources>
       <sys-lib> user32.lib kernel32.lib shell32 </sys-lib>
       <pic>on</pic>
       <postlink-command> mt.exe -manifest $(id).exe.manifest -outputresource:$(id).exe;1
       <postlink-command> del $(id).exe.manifest </postlink-command>
   </exe>
</makefile>
```

The batch is (genbake.bat):

```
bakefile -f msvc plain_exe.bkl -o Makefile.mak
call C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
nmake -f Makefile.mak
cmd
```

Trigger the batch to build everything.